# Plotting Financial Data with PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I have recently been interested in plotting financial data with `pgfplots`. The style I am trying to achieve is similar to what can be produced with gnuplot. However, I am familiar with `pgfplots` and have grown to love its output, which is why I would prefer to use the former. So far, I have been unable to find any similar attempts or examples.

I am trying to create plots which are similar to those which can be seen in [these gnuplot examples](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/finance.html). Clearly the line graphs are trivial, but what I am interested in is plotting using 'finance bars' and candlesticks, but primarily finance bars. Below I have included an example taken from the linked page.

Currently I don't know where to start with this. The gnuplot codes in the examples are very concise and I was hoping to achieve similar levels of concision with `pgfplots`. However, I am not sure if this is possible.

Does anyone know how to plot time series using finance bars or candlesticks using `pgfplots`? I would be interested to see what you can come up with.

[image: A graph with 'finance bars' in black.]

---

### UPDATE 1

I have had some time to fiddle around with this briefly. I am including something which is close to the candlestick format, and a small data file to illustrate this with. Thank you @Torbjørn T. for your answer that you linked—you will see it does most of the heavy lifting in the example.

aapl.csv:

```
date,open,high,low,close,volume
2013-02-08,67.7142,68.4014,66.8928,67.8542,158168416
2013-02-11,68.0714,69.2771,67.6071,68.5614,129029425
2013-02-12,68.5014,68.9114,66.8205,66.8428,151829363
2013-02-13,66.7442,67.6628,66.1742,66.7156,118721995
2013-02-14,66.3599,67.3771,66.2885,66.6556,88809154
2013-02-15,66.9785,67.1656,65.7028,65.7371,97924631
2013-02-19,65.8714,66.1042,64.8356,65.7128,108854046
2013-02-20,65.3842,65.3842,64.1142,64.1214,118891367
2013-02-21,63.7142,64.1671,63.2599,63.7228,111596821
2013-02-22,64.1785,64.5142,63.7999,64.4014,82583823
```

The almost working example code:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    boxplot prepared from table/.code={
        \def\tikz@plot@handler{\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplotprepared}%
        \pgfplotsset{
            /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
            #1,
        }
    },
    /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
        table/.code={\pgfplotstablecopy{#1}\to\boxplot@datatable},
        row/.initial=0,
        make style readable from table/.style={
            #1/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/row}}{##1}\of\boxplot@datatable
                \pgfplotsset{boxplot/#1/.expand once={\pgfplotsretval}}
            }
        },
        make style readable from table=lower whisker,
        make style readable from table=upper whisker,
        make style readable from table=lower quartile,
        make style readable from table=upper quartile,
        make style readable from table=median,
        make style readable from table=lower notch,
        make style readable from table=upper notch
}
\makeatother

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{aapl.csv}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    cycle list={{red},{black}},
    title={AAPL Candlestick Chart},
    xlabel={Date},
    ylabel={Price / USD}
    ]
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\TotalRows{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\TotalRows}
{
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared from table={
        table=\datatable,
        row=#1,
        lower whisker=low,
        upper whisker=high,
        lower quartile=open,
        upper quartile=close,
        median=close,
    },
    boxplot prepared={
        whisker extend=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot/box extend}*0,
        every whisker/.style={thick}  
    },
    fill,fill opacity=0.5,
    ]
    coordinates {};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have attached the output below; it is starting to look how I hoped it would. There are some areas that are not perfect. For instance, you can see the whiskers passing through the middle of the plot where the upper and lower quartile are listed the wrong way round. A quick and dirty fix for this is to set the opacity to 1.

I have set the colour cycle to red and black to inspire anyone that has an idea how to assign one intelligently, based on the data.

I welcome any improvements to this or attempts at the finance bars. Thanks again.
[image: my_candlesticks]

---

### UPDATE 2

I have played around with this a little more. Here is my solution that plots with finance bars. I think the idea can be extended to correctly formatting the candlesticks too if one wishes. I have had to manually set the limits. Maybe the best thing to do is run my previous solution first, plotted in white, to size the plot and then this over the top to generate the output.

Please see the code and output below. As before, any improvements are welcome.

```latex
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotsset{
    select row/.style={
        x filter/.code={\ifnum\coordindex=#1\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi}
    }
}

\newcommand{\financebar}[5]{
% takes arguements date (x coord), open, close, high, low 
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\draw (axis cs:#1,#5) -- (axis cs:#1,#4);}\tmp
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\draw (axis cs:#1,#2) -- (axis cs:{#1-0.5},#2);}\tmp
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\draw (axis cs:#1,#3) -- (axis cs:{#1+0.5},#3);}\tmp
}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{aapl.csv}\datatable
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    cycle list={{red},{black}},
    title={AAPL Finance Bar Chart},
    xlabel={Date},
    ylabel={Price / USD},
    xmin=0, xmax=11,
    ymin=63, ymax=69.75 
    ]
    
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\TotalRows{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\TotalRows}
{
    
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{open}\of{\datatable}\edef\openPrice{\pgfplotsretval}
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{close}\of{\datatable}\edef\closePrice{\pgfplotsretval}
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{high}\of{\datatable}\edef\highPrice{\pgfplotsretval}
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{low}\of{\datatable}\edef\lowPrice{\pgfplotsretval}

    \financebar{#1+1}{\openPrice}{\closePrice}{\highPrice}{\lowPrice}
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. I see from the Gnuplot manual that candlestick plots are very similar to boxplots. `pgfplots` can make boxplots (see section 5.12 *Statistics* in the manual), but I don't think there is any builtin way for making time series of box plots. I did find one question describing how to make multiple boxplots from a single data file (which it turned out I answered myself ..): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/399163/ It's perhaps not very elegant, but might be a start.

Comment: Hi there, I had a feeling that I would be steered towards the boxplots. They are very similar to the candlesticks and I am sure can be made more so with some tinkering. I also notice some similarities with the finance bars. I will play around with these and will post an update if I get to something resembling the gnuplot output. Thanks for taking a look and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @FoxCharles I'd be much interested in your answer :)

Comment: @FoxCharles Maybe can you add to your question a set of data with open/high/low/close price ? It would help building the asymetrical boxplot (the candlestick).  The different lines would probably be different moving average that Tikz could calculate too.

Comment: @FoxCharles a visual like https://www.cmcmarkets.com/en/trading-guides/what-are-candlestick-charts could help others to see the specificities of candlesticks (and create conditions on style whether the open is higher than close and vice cersa)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. For this type of graph we would need to have a much narrower width. How can you modify the width of the boxplot ?

Comment: @JeT Looking at the manual (page 502 for version dated 29 Feb 2020), you can set the width with the `box extend` key. The width is given in axis units, so not ideal for this usecase. There is also a `whisker extend` key.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Not ideal indeed :/ a candlestick is a function of 4 parameters open/close (that defines a rectangle with 2 points as tikz does) and high/low (that just defines the vertical segment). These can probably be wrapped in a .pic (?) The question of the width could be fixed by the user.

Comment: I believe you will need to construct each box individually if you want to apply a distinctive colour according to whether the daily price has increased or dropped, which is how candlestick plots are constructed. This suggests you will need to put `addplot+` in a loop to construct each box individually and apply the appropriate colour. This answer by @Mike [Changing colors in plot pgfplots loading data from pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439293/89098) colours individual bars according to a value in the datafile for a barplot..

Answer (score 3):

We can use `R` for this by retrieving the relevant data using the `tq_get` function from the `tidyquant` package and plotting the candlestick and moving average using `ggplot`, a function in the `tidyverse` collection of packages. This example largely follows Matt Dancho's vignette for his `tidyquant` package posted here: [Charting with tidyquant](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyquant/vignettes/TQ04-charting-with-tidyquant.html#candlestick-chart)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

<<Setup,echo=FALSE>>=
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(tikzDevice)
})

theme_set(theme_bw() +
          theme(axis.text.x     = element_text(face="bold",size=14,angle=0, hjust=0.5),
                axis.text.y     = element_text(face="bold",size=14,hjust=1),
                axis.title      = element_text(face="bold",size=16),
                plot.title      = element_text(face="bold",size=14)))
@

<<GetData,echo=FALSE>>=
#https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyquant/vignettes/TQ04-charting-with-tidyquant.html#candlestick-chart
# Get AAPL and AMZN Stock Prices
start <- as_date("2015-09-01")
end <- as_date("2017-01-15")
AAPL <- tq_get("AAPL", get = "stock.prices", from = start, to = end)

@

\begin{document}
<<Candlestick,device='tikz',echo=FALSE>>=
AAPL %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = close)) +
    geom_candlestick(aes(open = open, high = high, low = low, close = close)) +
    geom_ma(ma_fun = SMA, n = 3, linetype = "dotted", size = 1.25,color="green") +
    labs(title = "AAPL Candlestick Chart",
         subtitle = "24 Nov 2016 - 15 Jan 2017",
         y = "Closing Price", x = "") + 
    coord_x_date(xlim = c(as_date("2016-11-24"), end+days(2)),
                 ylim = c(105, 120))
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. My first downvote.

Comment: Hi Ross, I was hoping for a solution that uses `pgfplots`. Whilst this is in the spirit of using tikz and moving away from gnuplot it is not quite what I am attempting to do. If you can manage the same with `pgfplots` I will happily accept that answer. Thanks.