# Horizontal bar chart with different colors for each bar

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to create a horizontal bar chart with different labels on the y-axis for each bar. Also, the value should be displayed on the right-hand side of each bar.

Fx:

"Test A" ... red bar ... 400

"Test B" ... orange bar...150
etc.

**Current output**

[image]

**Current code**

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newlength{\xdim}

\definecolor{findOptimalPartition}{HTML}{D7191C}
\definecolor{storeClusterComponent}{HTML}{FDAE61}
\definecolor{dbscan}{HTML}{ABDDA4}
\definecolor{constructCluster}{HTML}{2B83BA}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    legend style={
    legend columns=4,
        at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},
        anchor=north,
        draw=none
    },
    ytick=data,
    axis y line*=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick={0,100,200,300,400,500,600},
    width=.9\textwidth,
    bar width=6mm,
    yticklabels={{Test A}, 
    {Test B}, 
    {Test C}, 
    {Test D}, 
    {Test E}, 
    {Test F}},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=600,
    area legend,
    y=8mm,
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.625},
]
\addplot[findOptimalPartition,fill=findOptimalPartition] coordinates
{(400,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0)};
\addplot[storeClusterComponent,fill=storeClusterComponent] coordinates
{(0,0) (150,1) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0)};
\addplot[dbscan,fill=dbscan] coordinates
{(0,0) (0,0) (250,2) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0)};
\addplot[constructCluster,fill=constructCluster] coordinates
{(0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (50,3) (0,0) (0,0)};
\addplot[blue,fill=blue] coordinates
{(0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (350,4) (0,0)};
\addplot[green,fill=green] coordinates
{(0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (100,5)};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{X}
\label{fig:stats}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason I can't open the link of the output.

Comment: The link of the output? Do you mean the code or the image?

Comment: No. In your post appears "Current output" and one link to be open. That is I can see.

Comment: @juanuni It's an image and it shows perfectly here.

Comment: @Saud ...but your code is incomplete.

Comment: Here's a way to do this using PGFPlots: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37568/colors-and-legend-in-groupplots-barplot

Comment: Thx for the link, Jake. But it looks like each plot is using just one color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve that using pgfplot, but with simple tikz you could adapt this (using a `foreach` loop):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{findOptimalPartition}{HTML}{D7191C}
\definecolor{storeClusterComponent}{HTML}{FDAE61}
\definecolor{dbscan}{HTML}{ABDDA4}
\definecolor{constructCluster}{HTML}{2B83BA}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach  \l/\x/\c[count=\y] in {find optimal partition/2/findOptimalPartition, store cluster component/3/storeClusterComponent, database scan/1.5/dbscan, construct cluster/2.2/constructCluster}
{\node[left] at (0,\y) {\l};
\draw[fill=\c] (0,\y-.4) rectangle (\x,\y+.4);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*UPDATE*

Pure tikz again:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{findOptimalPartition}{HTML}{D7191C}
\definecolor{storeClusterComponent}{HTML}{FDAE61}
\definecolor{dbscan}{HTML}{ABDDA4}
\definecolor{constructCluster}{HTML}{2B83BA}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(.01,0)}]
\foreach  \l/\x/\c[count=\y] in {find optimal partition/400/findOptimalPartition, 
store cluster component/150/storeClusterComponent, 
database scan/250/dbscan, 
construct cluster/50/constructCluster}
{\node[left] at (0,\y) {\l};
\fill[\c] (0,\y-.4) rectangle (\x,\y+.4);
\node[right] at (\x, \y) {\x};}
\draw (0,0) -- (600,0);
\foreach \x in {100, 200, ..., 600}
{\draw (\x,.2) -- (\x,0) node[below] {\x};}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use other pgfplots this will probably not be consistent with these plots.

With pgfplots, `nodes near coords` probably is the way to go.

Comment: Thx, Christoph. Hmm, how would you add the x-axis and the value of each bar?

Answer (score 7):

First of all set `compat`:

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
```

Current version is 1.13. AFAIK you have to use at least version 1.11, if you want to use `xbar stacked` together with `nodes near coords`.

Use `ytick={0,...,5}` instead `ytick=data` or maybe better use all `y` coordinates for the first plot:

```
\addplot[findOptimalPartition,fill] coordinates
  {(400,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
```

For the value on the right side of each bar you can use `nodes near coords`. But then you have to change its position:

```
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords style={text=black, at ={(\pgfplotspointmeta,\pgfplotspointy)},anchor=west},
visualization depends on=y \as \pgfplotspointy,
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}% <- needed!!

\definecolor{findOptimalPartition}{HTML}{D7191C}
\definecolor{storeClusterComponent}{HTML}{FDAE61}
\definecolor{dbscan}{HTML}{ABDDA4}
\definecolor{constructCluster}{HTML}{2B83BA}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    legend style={
    legend columns=4,
        at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},
        anchor=north,
        draw=none
    },
    ytick=data,
    axis y line*=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick={0,100,...,600},
    width=.9\textwidth,
    bar width=6mm,
    yticklabels={{Test A}, 
    {Test B}, 
    {Test C}, 
    {Test D}, 
    {Test E}, 
    {Test F}},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=600,
    area legend,
    y=8mm,
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.625},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={text=black, at ={(\pgfplotspointmeta,\pgfplotspointy)},anchor=west},
    visualization depends on=y \as \pgfplotspointy,
    every axis plot/.append style={fill}
]
\addplot[findOptimalPartition] coordinates
  {(400,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[storeClusterComponent] coordinates
  {(0,0) (150,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[dbscan,fill=dbscan] coordinates
  {(0,0) (0,1) (250,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[constructCluster] coordinates
  {(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (50,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[blue] coordinates
  {(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (350,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[green] coordinates
  {(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (100,5)};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{X}
\label{fig:stats}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

But the suggestion of @Jake in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37660/43317 is better:

Use

```
xbar=0pt,
/pgf/bar shift=0pt,
```

instead `xbar stacked`. Then you have to write only the disered coordinate for each plot and the code for the values at each bar simplifies to

```
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords style={text=black},
```

AFAIK the following code would work also with older pgfplots versions.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\definecolor{findOptimalPartition}{HTML}{D7191C}
\definecolor{storeClusterComponent}{HTML}{FDAE61}
\definecolor{dbscan}{HTML}{ABDDA4}
\definecolor{constructCluster}{HTML}{2B83BA}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar=0pt,
    /pgf/bar shift=0pt,
    legend style={
    legend columns=4,
        at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},
        anchor=north,
        draw=none
    },
    ytick={0,...,5},
    ytick style={draw=none},% <- added
    axis y line*=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick={0,100,...,600},
    width=.9\textwidth,
    bar width=6mm,
    yticklabels={{Test A}, 
    {Test B}, 
    {Test C}, 
    {Test D}, 
    {Test E}, 
    {Test F}},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=600,
    area legend,
    y=8mm,
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.625},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={text=black},
    every axis plot/.append style={fill}
]
\addplot[findOptimalPartition] coordinates {(400,0)};
\addplot[storeClusterComponent] coordinates {(150,1)};
\addplot[dbscan,fill=dbscan] coordinates {(250,2)};
\addplot[constructCluster] coordinates {(50,3)};
\addplot[blue] coordinates {(350,4)};
\addplot[green] coordinates {(100,5)};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{X}
\label{fig:stats}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.