# How can multiple pgfplotstable columns be used in a legend?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'd like to plot a few sets of data using the `groupplots` library of `pgfplots`.  On each plot, I'd like to add a few other pieces of data that do not change from plot to plot.  So I put the plot commands in a `\foreach` loop, but I can't get the legend entries to come from the input table describing these extra data.  I tried something similar to the top answer in [Use first row of a table as legend entry in pgfplot graph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23993/use-first-row-of-a-table-as-legend-entry-in-pgfplot-graph), but it would not compile (when resolving references the second time around it did not like `\colname`).

Below is an example and the output.  The correct answer will rename the labels from 'Model' to the columns from `\modeltable`.  (It would also be nice to space the labels a bit further out in the horizontal direction...)

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{% global config
  compat=newest,
  every minor tick={very thin, gray},
  minor tick num=4,
  enlargelimits=0.02,
  group style={
    columns=2,
    xlabels at=edge bottom,
    ylabels at=edge left},
  every axis legend/.append style={
    legend cell align=left,
    legend columns=4
  }
}

\pgfplotstableread{
  Time      {Model A}   {Model G}   {Model Z}
  0         1           1           1
  1         1           2           2
  2         2           3           3
  3         3           4           4
  4         5           5           8
  5         8           6           10
  6         13          7           16
}\modeltable

\pgfplotstableread{
  Time      {Data 1}  {Data 2}
  0         1.3       2.3
  1         2.6       3.6
  2         3.8       4.8
  3         7.9       5.9
  4         6.3       7.3
  5         7.5       6.5
  6         9.0       8.9
}\datatable

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{groupplot}[
      xlabel={Time},
      ylabel={Amplitude},
      every axis title shift=0,
      legend to name=grouplegend]

      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2}{%
        \nextgroupplot[title=Data $#1$]

        % Models
        \foreach \y in {1, 2, 3} {
          \addplot [smooth, dashed, color=DarkRed]
            table[x index=0, y index=\y] {\modeltable};
          %\pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{\y}\of{\modeltable}\to{\colname}
          %\addlegendentry {\colname}
          \addlegendentry{Model}
        }

        % Data
        \addplot [only marks, mark=o]
          table[x index=0, y index=#1] {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry {Data}
      }

    \end{groupplot}

    \node (dummytitle) at ($(group c1r1.north)!0.5!(group c2r1.north)$)
      [above]{};
    \node (title) at (dummytitle.north)
      [above, yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/every axis title shift}]
      {Experimental Data};

    \node (legend) at ($(group c1r1.south)!0.5!(group c2r1.south)$)
      [below, yshift=-2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/every axis title shift}]
      {\ref{grouplegend}};

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Two-column plot with uninformative legend]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the entries you add using `\addlegendentry` are not expanded, so they all consist of just `\colname` at the time when the legend is called, which is outside the scope where `\colname` is defined. This can be fixed by using `\addlegendentryexpanded{...}` instead.

I've also taken the liberty to add a little more space between the legend entries (as described in [How can I adjust the horizontal spacing between legend entries in PGFPlots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18152/how-can-i-adjust-the-horizontal-spacing-between-legend-entries-in-pgfplots)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{% global config
  compat=newest,
  every minor tick={very thin, gray},
  minor tick num=4,
  enlargelimits=0.02,
  group style={
    columns=2,
    xlabels at=edge bottom,
    ylabels at=edge left},
  every axis legend/.append style={
    legend cell align=left,
    legend columns=4
  }
}

\pgfplotstableread{
  Time      {Model A}   {Model G}   {Model Z}
  0         1           1           1
  1         1           2           2
  2         2           3           3
  3         3           4           4
  4         5           5           8
  5         8           6           10
  6         13          7           16
}\modeltable

\pgfplotstableread{
  Time      {Data 1}  {Data 2}
  0         1.3       2.3
  1         2.6       3.6
  2         3.8       4.8
  3         7.9       5.9
  4         6.3       7.3
  5         7.5       6.5
  6         9.0       8.9
}\datatable

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{groupplot}[
      xlabel={Time},
      ylabel={Amplitude},
      every axis title shift=0,
      legend to name=grouplegend,
      legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}
     ]

      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2}{%
        \nextgroupplot[title=Data $#1$]

        % Models
        \foreach \y in {1, 2, 3} {
          \addplot [smooth, dashed, color=DarkRed]
            table[x index=0, y index=\y] {\modeltable};

          \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{\y}\of{\modeltable}\to{\colname}
          \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
        }

        % Data
        \addplot [only marks, mark=o]
          table[x index=0, y index=#1] {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry {Data}
      }

    \end{groupplot}

    \node (dummytitle) at ($(group c1r1.north)!0.5!(group c2r1.north)$)
      [above]{};
    \node (title) at (dummytitle.north)
      [above, yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/every axis title shift}]
      {Experimental Data};

    \node (legend) at ($(group c1r1.south)!0.5!(group c2r1.south)$)
      [below, yshift=-2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/every axis title shift}]
      {\ref{grouplegend}};

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the `\addlegendentry{Model}` line still be in the `\foreach` loop?

Comment: @sappjw: Oops, no, it should not.