# Adding a legend header

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to add a legend header to one of my pgfplot. So far I get that

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    enlargelimits=false,
    legend pos=north west,
    legend style={area legend},
    legend columns=-1
   ]
   \addlegendimage{empty legend}
   \addlegendentry[yshift=10pt]{Header legend}
   \addplot
     [const plot,fill=blue,draw=black]
     coordinates
     {(0,0.1)    (0.1,0.15)  (0.2,0.5)   (0.3,0.62)
      (0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58)  (0.6,0.65)  (0.7,0.6)
      (0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55)  (1,0.52)}
     \closedcycle;
   \addlegendentry{histo 1}
   \addplot
      [const plot,fill=red,draw=black]
     coordinates
     {(0,0.1)    (0.1,0.15)  (0.2,0.5)   (0.3,0.62)
      (0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58)  (0.6,0.65)  (0.7,0.6)
      (0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55)  (1,0.52)}
     \closedcycle;
   \addlegendentry{histo 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives me that

[image]

I would like to have the second row to be left aligned with respect to the first one. I do not want to fix the number of row because there may be more histograms to come and I would like to have them horizonthally aligned (that's why I use `legend columns=-1`).

I read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18152/how-can-i-adjust-the-horizontal-spacing-between-legend-entries-in-pgfplots) that pgfplots `legend` is nothing else than tikz `matrix` so maybe there is a way to x-shift the second row (as I already did with the `yshift=10pt` command).

Comment: So you want some sort of multicolumn matrix? This is unsupported by PGF's `\matrix` as far as I know. A patch has been proposed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1388/multirow-multicolumn-cells-in-tikz-matrices - perhaps that might work here as well

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: I saw this answer yesterday but I didn't get time to try it. I will edit my question if I can make it work.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: I didn't manage to make it work but I find another way to do it (see the answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `legend` style I find something a bit crappy but working. Here is a possible solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    enlargelimits=false,
    legend pos=north west,
    legend style={area legend,
      /tikz/row 1 column 2/.append style={column sep=-2.3cm}},
    legend columns=-1
   ]
   \addlegendimage{empty legend}
   \addlegendentry[yshift=10pt]{Header legend}
   \addplot
     [const plot,fill=blue,draw=black]
     coordinates
     {(0,0.1)    (0.1,0.15)  (0.2,0.5)   (0.3,0.62)
      (0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58)  (0.6,0.65)  (0.7,0.6)
      (0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55)  (1,0.52)}
     \closedcycle;
   \addlegendentry{histo 1}
   \addplot
      [const plot,fill=red,draw=black]
     coordinates
     {(0,0.1)    (0.1,0.15)  (0.2,0.5)   (0.3,0.62)
      (0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58)  (0.6,0.65)  (0.7,0.6)
      (0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55)  (1,0.52)}
     \closedcycle;
   \addlegendentry{histo 2}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, the `column sep=-2.3cm` really depends on the text width of the header which may vary from one plot to another.