# How can we change the font type and add a space in legend of a bar graph?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

Can i change the style of my legend (to have a space between them and also look more academic graph?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \X in {1,...,9}
{\ifnum\X=1
\edef\mylst{Testing1}
\else
\edef\mylst{\mylst,Testing\X}
\fi}
\begin{axis}[symbolic x coords/.expanded=\mylst,
    ylabel=Number,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    x tick label style={anchor=north west,rotate=-30},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(Testing1,9) (Testing2,4)
         (Testing3,4) (Testing4,1) (Testing5,1) (Testing6,8) (Testing7,1) (Testing8,1) (Testing9,1)};
\addplot  
    coordinates {(Testing1,3) (Testing2,5)
         (Testing3,5) (Testing4,4) (Testing5,5) (Testing6,7) (Testing7,0) (Testing8,0) (Testing9,0)};
\legend{Series 1, Series2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first part of your question has already an answer: add something like `/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18162. However, I do not know what you mean by a more academic look? (Do you mean even more boring?  just kidding;-)

Comment: It needs to go into `legend style`: `legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}},`. If you tell me what you mean by "more academic" I may attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks, i finally found that. I added in 2 `legend style`. Anyway, my question about `more academic` is the legend current shown have `2 bar` in each legand, it looks too fancy and less professional. I prefer to have `one bar` in each legand.

Comment: That's very easy with `legend image code`. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two subquestions.

1. The question of how one can increase the distance between the legend entries has been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18162): just add `/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=<some distance>}` to `legend style`.
2. In order to change the appearance of the legend images, you can define your own `legend image code`. Below is an example.

There is also the question in the title of how one may change the font type, but this seems not required. Anyway, you can add `font=\sffamily`, I added this but commented it out in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16,
/pgfplots/aan ybar legend/.style={
/pgfplots/legend image code/.code={
\draw [##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=4.5pt,yshift=-0.3em,bar shift=1pt,yscale=2]
plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em) };}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \X in {1,...,9}
{\ifnum\X=1
\edef\mylst{Testing1}
\else
\edef\mylst{\mylst,Testing\X}
\fi}
\begin{axis}[symbolic x coords/.expanded=\mylst,
    ylabel=Number,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    x tick label style={anchor=north west,rotate=-30},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1,%font=\sffamily,
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=1.2em}},
    ybar,aan ybar legend
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(Testing1,9) (Testing2,4)
         (Testing3,4) (Testing4,1) (Testing5,1) (Testing6,8) (Testing7,1) (Testing8,1) (Testing9,1)};
\addplot  
    coordinates {(Testing1,3) (Testing2,5)
         (Testing3,5) (Testing4,4) (Testing5,5) (Testing6,7) (Testing7,0) (Testing8,0) (Testing9,0)};
\legend{Series 1, Series 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Schordinger's cat. Thanks. Brillant. Overleaf can do many changes

Comment: @aan I am sorry to partly spoil your enthusiasm: this has nothing to do with overleaf, it is all due to the pgfplots package (by C. Feuersänger), which is based on Ti*k*Z (by T. Tantau). I do not use overleaf but can use these packages as well.